# html making table borders invisible

Tags: html, drupal

I use Drupal 6 with theme [summertime](http://drupal.org/project/summertime). Also I use FCKeditor. In order to align content I wanted to create a table with invisible borders. First I tried FCKEditor table properties and I gave 0 to border size in order to make borders invisible. But it did not work. I looked up the source and non working code was like below (Why giving border="0" did not work?) :

```
<table width="468" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" style="width: 468px; height: 201px;">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
            <h2 class="rtecenter"><a href="http://mydomain.com/url"><strong>Content </strong></a></h2>
            </td>
            <td><img src="/sites/mydomain.com/files/sample.jpg" alt="" /></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Then I tried:

```
<table width="468" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="border: medium hidden ; width: 468px; height: 201px;">
```

Table borders are now invisible but cell borders are still visible. How can I make it totally invisible. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The border attribute should be specified on the cell level, eg `<td style="border: 0;">`. Of course, this should be made in CSS using:

```
table td { border: 0; }
```

But I see that in your case that might be difficult.

Answer (score 1):

It should be done like this:

```
<table width="468" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" style="width: 468px; height: 201px;">
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td style="border: 0">
        <h2 class="rtecenter"><a href="http://mydomain.com/url"><strong>Content </strong></a></h2>
        </td>
        <td style="border: 0"><img src="/sites/mydomain.com/files/sample.jpg" alt="" /></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Answer (score 1):

There are probably borders set in the CSS.  Drupal core's system.css sets some borders on table headers and body that can be a pain to override.

You can add a custom CSS file to the theme so you avoid editing its CSS directly.  Simply add the path to your added .css file in the theme's .info file.

Then try adding:

```
tbody,
thead,
thead th,
tr.even,
tr.odd {
  border: 0;
}
```

Don't forget to turn off CSS aggregation and clear your cache.

Comment: good catch but I just want to apply invisible border to a certain page. Summertime already have a local.css file if I wrote custome css at there it will overwrite in everywhere which I dont want. Ifyou know how to restrict it to certain pages please let me know.

Comment: Your theme may have classes placed on the <body> tag per page.  Check if there's a unique class there, or somewhere in a <div> wrapping the node that you can target.  Or you could target it just in .content (or something similar) which will only be inside node content.

If none of these work for you, you can also add this to the wrapper div in your node.tpl.php file:
id="node-<?php print $node->nid; ?>"

Answer (score 1):

I just happened upon this while searching for something else. This is old, but thought I'd comment anyway. Someone else might find it helpful.

Rather than do a few of the things mentioned above, it would be simpler to just add a specific ID or CLASS name to the table itself, then you could specify settings just for that table in the CSS.

HTML:

```
<table .... id="exampleclass">
```

CSS:

```
#exampleclass tbody,
#exampleclass thead, 
#exampleclass th { 
  border: 0; 
}
```