# how to remove horizontal border of a table in bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

how to remove horizontal border of a table using bootstrap?
I want to keep only vertical border.
Here is my code:

```
<table class="table table-bordered">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Home</th>
            <th>Client</th>
            <th>Setting</th>
        </tr>   
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>data1</td>
            <td>data2</td>
            <td>data3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>data1</td>
            <td>data2</td>
            <td>data3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>data1</td>
            <td>data2</td>
            <td>data3</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: You have a Twitter Bootstrap table and you want to remove the horizontal border using CSS?

Comment: possible duplicate of [html making table borders invisible](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1992767/html-making-table-borders-invisible). The question is about Drupal, but since it''s just HTML & CSS the same answer should hold.

Comment: Your title contradicts your question :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Never use !important as it is a bad practice. The solution for your question is

```
.table-bordered > tbody > tr > td,
.table-bordered > thead > tr > td,
.table-bordered {
    border-bottom: 0;
    border-top: 0;
}
```

All the horizontal borders are gone and only the vertical borders are left.

Comment: we can add our own class or id to the table and can use this style simple, by adding class or id we won't have to use !important.

Comment: You forgot to add `th` (for sake of completeness)

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
table.table.table-bordered td{
    border: 0 none !important;
}
```

This removes all borders from the table.

Answer (score 0):

```css
.table.table-bordered.vertical,
.table.table-bordered.vertical td,
.table.table-bordered.vertical th{
  border-top: 0px solid white !important;
  border-bottom: 0px solid white !important;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</head>
  
<body>
<div class="container">
<table class="table table-bordered vertical">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Home</th>
            <th>Client</th>
            <th>Setting</th>
        </tr>   
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>data1</td>
            <td>data2</td>
            <td>data3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>data1</td>
            <td>data2</td>
            <td>data3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>data1</td>
            <td>data2</td>
            <td>data3</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Is this what you are looking for? you are adding the border by *explicitly* adding the table-bordered class. To remove the vertical borders we are adding a vertical class which will remove the top and bottom borders from all th and td elements.

Note: Its not good practice to replace the original behavior. So, I am instead extending it. Now `table table-bordered vertical` will yield vertical borders meanwhile `table table-bordered` will render its original version.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Write this:

```
table.table td, table.table th, table.table tr{
   border:none !important;
}
```